# How to alert a php array in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, json

I know that this question is so simple to ask, but I wasn't able to find the right answer for it, by going through many questions on stack overflow or by googling. So I found noway but to place the question here.

I have a mysql table as follow:

```
 [0]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
 [1]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
 [2]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
 [3]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
 [4]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
 [5]1>>>>2>>>>>3>>>>>5>>>>>6
```

I need to store it in a variable and parse it with json back to the ajax function, but the result I get is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Here is the php code:

```
 $ent = $_POST['id'];
 $column = array();
 $gtord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order WHERE oId = '$ent' ");
 while($rowmnu2=mysql_fetch_assoc($gtord))           
{
   $column[]  = array($rowmnu2);
}
  echo json_encode($column);
```

here is the ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "profile/ajax/getorder.php",
  data: {id:gotid},
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
     },
   });
```

I am sure that there is an error in my ajax code success alert, but I am not able to figure it out, how to go through the received array.

Please help me. Appreciated in advance.

Comment: Try $column[] = $rowmnu2

Comment: @Nouphal.M, I did try that too, the php file itself will echo the whole array correctly, but the ajax still alerts object :(

Comment: If you want to go through the received array, write a `for` loop. `alert()` doesn't show the contents of objects, use `console.log()` to see the data.

Comment: @Barmar, ok I'll need to search about how to use console.log then :(, but is that the only way ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```